# Why write * sign before declaring a struct variable, which has a self referencing pointer in C?

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I was making a linked list in C, then a query raised in my mind that (read the title above)

```
struct node
{
    int data;
    char age;
} temp;

// versus
struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node* next;
} *temp;
```

Answer (score 1):

A struct like `node` cannot contain itself. If this were allowed, each `struct node` variable would be infinitely sized.

`struct node* next;` is a *pointer* to a `struct node` value. A pointer has a known, finite size and thus a struct can contain a pointer to another value of the same type. By having a pointer to a next `struct node` you are creating a linked list. This pointer can also be `NULL` which allows your list to have an end.

Comment: I don't think this answers the question, it seems that they're asking why have `*temp` rather than just `temp` in the second case.